# Getting 401 from private NuGet when accessing it from Docker Image

Tags: docker, nuget

Im trying to do a "dotnet restore" when building my Docker image. I have created a Personal Access Token (PAT) from my TFS, with "all scopes" specified

This is from my Dockerfile:

```
...
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-nanoserver-1809 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY NuGet.config MyProj/
COPY ["MyProj/MyProj.csproj", "MyProj/"]    
RUN dotnet restore "MyProj/MyProj.csproj" --configfile MyProj\NuGet.Config 
...
```

This is my nuget.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />    
    <add key="MyCompany" value="https://tfs.mycompany.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/MyNugets/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <MyCompany>
      <add key="Username" value="myname" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="{The PAT}" />
    </MyCompany>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

This is the error message

> Step 13/22 : RUN dotnet restore "MyProj/MyProj.csproj" --configfile
>   MyProj\NuGet.Config  ---> Running in f9d59d4105eb C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.402\NuGet.targets(123,5): error : **Unable to
>   load the service index for source**
>   https://tfs.mycompany.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/MyNuGets/nuget/v3/index.json.
>   [C:\src\MyProj\MyProj.csproj] C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.402\NuGet.targets(123,5): error :   **Response
>   status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).**
>   [C:\src\MyProj\MyProj.csproj] The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet restore
>   "MyProj/MyProj.csproj" --configfile MyProj\NuGet.Config' returned a
>   non-zero code: 1

This is my face when I see this

> :(

So... What Im I missing? (yes I will parameterize the PAT, when I get things working)

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?